# Почему file_put_contents записывает не все содержимое?

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему file_put_contents в моем коде ниже, записывает не все содержимое, как исправить?

Строка `echo $category = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $category);` отображает все, что должно быть записано в файл, а в файл пишутся только данные из последней категории.

```
<?php

if (preg_match_all('~<Category>.+?</Category>~s', $str, $categories)) {

$i = 1;

foreach ($categories[0] as $category) {

        $temp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "<Catalog>$category</Catalog>";

        $category = str_replace(['<Category>','</Category>'], ["",""], $category);

        $category = str_replace('<Site>', '<Site><Category_ID>'.$i.'</Category_ID>', $category);

        $category = preg_replace('~<Name>(.+?)</Name>~', "", $category);

        $category = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "", $category);

        echo $category = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $category);

        $filename = '5.xml';

        file_put_contents($filename, $category = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", '
<Catalog>
<Category>
'.$category.'
</Category>
</Catalog>')); 

}

$i++;

}
```

Comment: А зачем вы применяете iconv для $category дважды?

Comment: echo у меня просто, чтобы видеть результат, второй раз для сохранения в файл

Comment: Нет, ваш echo изменяет $category, потому что вы там написали `$category =`. Следовательно iconv применяется для $category дважды

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас вообще удалил эту строку, все равно, сохраняются не все данные.

Comment: Пройдитесь дебаггером, включите показ ошибок.

Comment: «в файл пишутся только данные из последней категории» — это как бы логично, потому что [в документации русским по белому написано](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php), что file_put_contents полностью перезаписывает содержимое файла новым

Comment: В той же документации пишут про FILE_APPEND

Comment: Я читал документацию, у меня по разному пишет, то последние данные, то первые данные. Теперь я понял, что file_put_contents не подходит для моей задачи. Можете помочь сохранить в файл все содержимое $category ?

Comment: Дебагер ошибок не показывает. `ini_set("display_errors", "On");
`

Comment: Плохо читали документацию, читайте ещё, про FILE_APPEND

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Записал полностью.